# How can I write numbers on the fields?

Tags: numbering, chess, chessboard

How can I write numbers on the fields?

[image: For examlpe I want to make something like this:]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In lack of a minimal working example I would dare say: Yes, you can ;-)

Comment: It depends on how you are drawing the fields. As SoundsOfSilence said, without an MWE it is impossible to say much more....

Comment: See page 54 of the chessboard documentation.

Comment: Find suliton!
 \chessboard[pgfstyle={text},
 text=
 \bfseries 2,
 markregions={a1-a1,a8-a8, h1-h1, h8-h8}, 
 showmover=false]

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Do you want to provide an answer?