# How can I add labels to each square in \chessboard using xskak?

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I searched a lot on the internet but I couldn't find any helpful answers, so here I am.
I'm trying to create a chessboard figure, using **xskak** package that contains a label for each square.
An example of what I'm trying to achieve is shown in the xskak tutorial on overleaf, linked [here](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chess_notation).

I'll also add a screenshot of the image I'm referring to:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is documented on p. 54 of the [`chessboard`](https://texdoc.org/pkg/chessboard) package documentation.

Comment: Please try to make your question self-contained.

Comment: or adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548147/2388